# Using multer with inmemory option and streaming into mongodb gridfs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs

The following priece of code works as expected: it reads a file that has been uploaded using multer [https://github.com/expressjs/multer] and streams it into gridfs. Im also able to steam this out of gridfs as well.

```
var target = gfs.createWriteStream({
            filename: fileItem.originalname,
            mode: 'w',
            metadata: metaData
        });

        fs.createReadStream(tempFile)
            .on('end', function () {
                console.log('File read and stored');
            })
            .on('error', function (err) {
                console.log('Error handling file ' + err);
            })
            .pipe(target);

        // Attach new file to document list
        target.on('close', function (file) {
            filesUploadedList.push(file._id);
```

`fileItem` is obtained from iterating over `req.files.file` which are the files uploaded.

However, I'm  trying to figure out the inMemory option for multer. If I set this to true then the `fileItem` will have the buffer populated. Just to note without this option the buffer/contents of the `fileItem` is empty which is why in the code above its reading from the `fileItem.location`.

What is the best way to populate the target with contents? the `fs.createReadStream` is doing the piping at the moment.

Thanks.

J

Comment: maybe you're interested 

  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357412/stored-files-directly-in-mongodb-with-gridfs-stream

Answer (score 5):

You can accomplish this by using [streamifier](https://github.com/gagle/node-streamifier). The code looks should look like this:

```
streamifier.createReadStream(fileItem.buffer).pipe(target);
```

Multer does not write anything to disk, target is now populated with a the buffer/contents of the file being uploaded.

Comment: var stream = streamifier.createReadStream(fileItem.buffer); then use the stream for anything.

Answer (score 5):

You could use it this way :

(original idea here: [stored files directly in mongodb with gridfs-stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28357412/stored-files-directly-in-mongodb-with-gridfs-stream))

```
app.post('/upload',multer({
    dest:"./tmp/",
    upload:null,// take uploading process 
    inMemory:true, //or false, not needed here

    onFileUploadStart:function(file){
       //set upload with WritableStream        
       this.upload = gfs.createWriteStream({
           filename:file.originalname,
           mode:"w",
           chunkSize:1024*4,
           content_type:file.mimetype,
           root:"fs",
           metadata: {} // put some crazy meta data in here
       });
    },

    onFileUploadData:function(file,data) {
       //put the chunks into db 
       this.upload.write(data);
    },

    onFileUploadComplete:function(file) {
       //end process 
       this.upload.end();
       console.log('successfully written File to MongoDB Gridfs');
    }
    }),
    function(req,res) {
       res.sendStatus(200);
   });
```

Since you are using the onFileUploadData()-function the Gridsfs would be populated as data arrives. This works regardlessly of setting inMemory to true or false. 
You should note, that the file.buffer[] can get very large if you are dealing with huge files. It's just a copy of all incoming data fragments.

In theory it might be better to use an own defined middleware on top of [busboy](https://github.com/mscdex/busboy) without performing file operations (as used in Multer) at all.

Comment: This cannot be accomplished using multer anymore, it accepts only two parameter, filename and dest

Comment: It actually can by using [StorageEngines](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/StorageEngine.md)