# stored files directly in mongodb with gridfs-stream

Tags: node.js, mongodb, file, gridfs-stream

I need save some files like: images,video,pdf... into mongodb, so i use gridfs-stream and express.js

```
var file = req.files.file; 
req.pipe(gfs.createWriteStream({
    filename:file.originalname,
    mode:"w",
    chunkSize:1024*4,
    content_type:file.mimetype,
    root:"fs"
})
res.send(200);
```

for testing i use postman and set an POST request this way:

```
 POST /fs/upload HTTP/1.1
 Host: localhost:5000
 Cache-Control: no-cache

 ----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
 Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="epic.png"
 Content-Type: image/png


  ----WebKitFormBoundaryE19zNvXGzXaLvS5C
```

the problem is that this way just store the data of the file:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54d14ec5b102fe401519a3c1"),
    "filename" : "epic.png",
    "contentType" : "image/png",
    "length" : 0,
    "chunkSize" : 4096,
    "uploadDate" : ISODate("2015-02-03T22:42:14.730Z"),
    "aliases" : null,
    "metadata" : null,
    "md5" : "993fb9ce262a96a81c79a38106147e95"
}
```

but not the content i mean de binary data for it, into mongodb is store for it the propety length is equal to 0, bacause has not any chunks in fs.chucks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading in blogs found the answer to streaming data directly at database with express.js,gridfs-stream.js and multer middleware that way:

```
var multer = require('multer');

app.post('/fs/upload', multer({
    upload: null,// take uploading process 

    onFileUploadStart: function (file) {
        //set upload with WritableStream        
        this.upload = gfs.createWriteStream({
            filename: file.originalname,
            mode: "w",
            chunkSize: 1024*4,
            content_type: file.mimetype,
            root: "fs"
        });
     },

     onFileUploadData: function (file, data) {
        //put the chucks into db 
        this.upload.write(data);
     },

     onFileUploadComplete: function (file) {
        //end process 
        this.upload.on('drain', function () {
            this.upload.end();
        });
     }
}), function (req, res) {
   res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

For testing this:

```
app.route('/fs/download/:file').get(function (req, res) {
   var readstream = gfs.createReadStream({_id: req.params.file});
   readstream.pipe(res);
});
```

Comment: Did this really work for you, because it didn't for me. The file was never put in the Gridfs, although i got an error, that end() is not a function.

Comment: Btw: Your example works now, if I remove the "drain" event function around "this.upload.end() ". Are there any problems if I implement it this way?

Comment: good point i not sure if the middleware multer takecare somethig like drain event when parsing files  may be with the property [inMemory](https://github.com/expressjs/multer#inmemory) that should work if multer use pipe or some similar in the otherwise colud use other middleware that use pipe